# How to query nested lists of lists in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a JSON collection in a form like this:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Shop 1",
    "goods": {
      "location": "Shop 1 middle",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": 1,
          "name": "Apple",
          "price": 10,
        },
        {
          "_id": 2,
          "name": "Milk",
          "price": 2,
        },
        {
          "_id": 3,
          "name": "Butter",
          "price": 5,
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Shop 2",
    "goods": {
      "location": "Shop 2 middle",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": 4,
          "name": "Apple",
          "price": 10,
        },
        {
          "_id": 5,
          "name": "Milk",
          "price": 2,
        },
        {
          "_id": 6,
          "name": "Butter",
          "price": 5,
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

POJO's like this:

```java
// Shop.java
@Document(collection = "shop")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Shop{

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Goods goods;
}

// Goods.java

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Goods{

    private String location;

    private List<Item> items;
}

// Item.java

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

public class Item{

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private double price;
}
```

I have to get all `items` from all the shops, and get an `item` by it's `_id` with the  name of a shop where it is. I tried having JPA repository methods that looks like this:

```
public interface ShopRepository extends MongoRepository<Shop, Integer> {

    List<Item> findAllItems();

    @Query(value = "{ 'goods.items.item._id': '?0' }", fields="{ 'name': 1, 
    'goods.location': 1 }")
    List<Shop> findItemWithDetails(int id);
}
```

Expected output of all items:

```json
[
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": 10,
    },
    {
      "_id": 2,
      "name": "Milk",
      "price": 2,
    },
    {
      "_id": 3,
      "name": "Butter",
      "price": 5,
    },
    {
      "_id": 4,
      "name": "Apple",
      "price": 10,
    },
    {
      "_id": 5,
      "name": "Milk",
      "price": 2,
    },
    {
      "_id": 6,
      "name": "Butter",
      "price": 5,
    }
]
```

Of an one item with it's location, if searched for item with id '4':

```json
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Shop 2",
    "goods": {
      "location": "Shop 2 middle",
      "items": [
        {
          "_id": 4,
          "name": "Apple",
          "price": 10,
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

This didn't seem to work. I am new to MongoDB so all this is confusing to me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add expected output to the question?

Comment: Added expected output.

Comment: What is the output you are getting from your current jpa function ?

Comment: Do you want `shop name` in the first output?

Comment: @DeepakPatankar I am always getting Shop with id=1 and all of it's items.

Comment: @NenadMilosavljevic no, only all of items in all of shops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GET ALL ITEMS**

- `$group` to group all items from all shops in one array (it will be array of arrays).
- `$project` and `$reduce` to merge inner arrays to one array
- `$unwind` to extract items from the array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "items": {
        "$addToSet": "$goods.items"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "items": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$items",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$items"
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_jSHv2NRxBs)

**GET ITEM BY ID**

- `$match` to find documents that have item with requested `_id`
- `$filter` to filter out only that particular item

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "goods.items._id": 4
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "goods.items": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$goods.items",
          "cond": {
            "$eq": [
              "$$this._id",
              4
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Working example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4GaRw2Ns5Yj)

Comment: Thank you! Can you also tell, how can this be achieved using MongoTemplate?

Comment: I added the second query in my answer also.

Comment: What do you mean by MongoTemplate? Are you using Mongoose?

Comment: No, it's java interface to directly access mongodb and dynamically create queries. But I believe I will learn that myself.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how you would do that in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to query in all items that are stored in your database it is better to create a new collection for your items, save _id of your items in your collection and use $lookup to query items. But if you don't want to change your collections you can use following aggregation to get desired outcome:

**All items**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$goods.items"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$goods.items"
    }
  }
])
```

**One Item by Id**

(WARNING: In this aggregation item field is an object not an array. If you want to get array as you mentioned in your question, you can use Nenad's answer.)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$goods.items"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "goods.items._id": 4
    }
  }
])
```